# bash: convert decimal to scientific including all decimals

Tags: bash, variables, type-conversion

I want to convert a decimal number to scientific notation such that all decimals excluding trailing zeroes are returned.

Example: `1230456.07890000` becomes `1.2304560789e6`
I know that using `result=$(printf "%e" ${number})` can give me the scientific notation, but it cuts the number off after the sixth decimal: `result=1.230456e+06`.
If I replace `"%e"` with for example `"%1.30e"` the inaccuracy changes the effective number.

Another problem with the `printf`command is that the exponent is always 2 digits long and shows a '+' when positive. I want the exponent to lose the leading zero and only show a sign if negative.

I hope somebody can help me with this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out how to get the desired result:

```
# Create variable defining number of significant decimals
# by removing '.' and leading zeroes
length=$(echo "${number}" | sed -e 's/[0]*$//g' -e 's/\.//g' -e 's/^[0]*//g')
length=$((${#length}-1));   # Determine the number of decimals to be displayed

# Get scientific number with correct accuracy
result=$(printf "%1.${length}e" ${number})

# Adjust the exponent (can also be done using StefanF's answer)
result="${result%[eE]*}e"$(echo "${result#*[eE]}" | sed -e 's/+//g' -e 's/^0//' -e 's/-0/-/')
```

The last part for adjusting the exponent (removing '+' and leading zero) can also be achieved using the purely bash-commands as StefanoF suggested.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a modifier to specify the number of position after the period:

```
printf "%.10e\n" ${number}
```

So you'll obtain `1.2304560789e+06`. After you can filter this result with some tricky substitution:

```
result=$(printf "%.10e\n" ${number})
result=${result/e+/e}
result=${result/e0/e}
result=${result/e-0/e}
```

At the end you'll obtain: `1.2304560789e6`.
(Fixed to add the case of negative exponent less than 10).

Comment: The problem with the first part of your solution is that the number of non-zero decimals may vary significantly, hence, just changing the `printf`-argument into `"%.10e"` doesn't do the trick for every number.
Another problem will be when the initial number is much smaller than 1: `number=0.0000001230456078900`
The last part solves the exponent-format correctly!

Comment: You first must decide the number of decimal digits you need to use. Whatever solution you'll find can't start from a different point.

Comment: I mean: if you want to use the scientific notation to solve a problem, you muse decide how precise must be your result. And you do this deciding the number of digits in your numbers. Anyway in your question you don't speak about the problem of the variable number of digits.

Comment: Some numbers are input-variables and therefore it is undesired to have more non-zero significant digits than the actual input has. This code is part of a lot bigger code that writes a script by itself. In order to be able to read it easily I want to keep the resulting values cleaned up.